# Load R data frame into Python and convert to Pandas data frame

Tags: python, r

I am trying to run the following code in an R data frame using Python.

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process
import os
import pandas as pd
import timeit
from rpy2.robjects import r
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
pandas2ri.activate()

start = timeit.default_timer()

def f(x):
    return fuzz.partial_ratio(str(x["sig1"]),str(x["sig2"]))

def fu_match(file):
    f1=r.load(file)
    f1=pandas2ri.ri2py(f1)
    f1["partial_ratio"]=f1.apply(f, axis=1)
    f1=f1.loc[f1["partial_ratio"]>90]
    f1.to_csv("test.csv")

stop = timeit.default_timer()
print stop - start 

fu_match('test_full.RData')
```

Here is the error.

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'apply'
```

I guess the problem has to do with the conversion from R to Pandas data frame. I know this is a repeated question, but I have tried all the solutions given to previous questions with no success.

Please, any help will be much appreciated.

EDIT: Here is the head of .RData.

```
  city                         sig1                         sig2
1    19 claudiopillonrobertoscolari  almeidabartolomeufrancisco
2    19 claudiopillonrobertoscolari cruzricardosantasergiosilva
3    19 claudiopillonrobertoscolari             costajorgesilva
4    19 claudiopillonrobertoscolari    costafrancisconaifesilva
5    19 claudiopillonrobertoscolari          camarajoseluizreis
6    19 claudiopillonrobertoscolari    almeidafilhojoaopimentel
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line

```
f1=pandas2ri.ri2py(f1)
```

is setting `f1` to be a `numpy.ndarray` when I think you expect it to be a `pandas.DataFrame`.

You can cast the array into a `DataFrame` with something like

```
f1 = pd.DataFrame(data=f1)
```

but you won't have your column names defined (which you use in `f(x)`). What is the structure of `test_full.RData`? Do you want to manually define your column names? If so

```
f1 = pd.DataFrame(data=f1, columns=("my", "column", "names"))
```

should do the trick.

*BUT* I would suggest you look at using a more standard data format, maybe `.csv`. `pandas` has good support for this, and I expect `R` does too. Check out [the](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_csv.html#pandas.DataFrame.from_csv) [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html).

Comment: Thanks @danodonovan. I've done as you said and I get this new error $ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1, 2), indices imply (3, 2)$. The code works when I read a test data in csv. The problem is that the data set is huge and converting it to cvs gives me a 50GB file. .RData is more efficient in storage.

Comment: I have added the head of the data frame to the question.

Comment: Without the full error trace I can't be of much help, which line is producing the ValueError? Ping me if you want to move this to a chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81406/q-load-r-data-frame-into-python-and-convert-to-pandas-data-frame

Comment: These two lines fixed my problem. Thanks a lot @danodonovan. print robjects.r.load(file) 
f1=com.load_data('test_full', package='reshape2')